# Unexpected token when using dynamic import instead System.import

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, webpack-3

After rewriting all my dynamic `System.import` calls to `import` webpack compilation fails:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: (...)/dashboard.js: Unexpected token (7:4)

   5 | 
   6 | export default Promise.all([
>  7 |     import('charts')
     |     ^
```

---

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: 
{
  loaders: [
    {
      test:    /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader:  'babel-loader'
    },
   (...)
}
```

---

`.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["syntax-dynamic-import", "transform-runtime"]
}
```

---

`package.json`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "~6.5.3",
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-cli": "~6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",      
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "noty": "~2.4.0",
    "path": "~0.12.7",
    "promise-polyfill": "~6.0.2",
    "resolve-url-loader": "~1.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "~4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "~0.13.1",
    "stylelint": "~7.6.0",
    "tag-it": "~2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "~0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.2.1",
    "webpack-uglify-js-plugin": "~1.1.9",
    "whatwg-fetch": "~2.0.2"
  },
```

Comment: Can you include the full error message with stacktrace?

Comment: Are you perhaps running the wrong version of Webpack? If you're running it via a CLI, perhaps you're using a globally-installed Webpack instead of the one listed in your `package.json`? Your Webpack config looks like one for 1.x, but your package says you're using 3.x. `1.x` will not work with your current Babel config.

Comment: Good notice, I was running old webpack from global npm instance, but the core problem was with not found `.babelrc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out my `.babelrc` was ignored, because this file (and webpack) was outside of my project's root directory. I fixed it by adding path to config file in `webpack.config.js` to `babel-loader`:

```
{
    test:    /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use:     'babel-loader?extends='+path.resolve('./.babelrc')
}
```

Comment: If the config is outside the root, you might as well just put the config in your Webpack config directly.

Answer (score 1):

Install this babel Plugin https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node

```
in .babelrc
{
  "plugins": ["dynamic-import-node"]
}`
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to import a transformer too like [`dynamic-import-webpack`](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack). These plugins already include the required syntax as a dependency, so your config can be simply:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["dynamic-import-webpack", "transform-runtime"]
}
```

Comment: That plugin is only needed for Webpack 1.x. v2 and v3 support `import()` in their own.